# Output: mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, nfs, vagrantfile

I am trying out the Kubernetes NFS volume claim in a replication controller example [1].

I have setup the NFS server, PV and PVC. And my replication controller looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: node-manager
  labels:
    name: node-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: node-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: node-manager
    spec:
      containers:
      -
        name: node-manager
        image: org/node-manager-1.0.0:1.0.0
        ports:
        -
          containerPort: 9763
          protocol: "TCP"
        -
          containerPort: 9443
          protocol: "TCP"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: nfs
            mountPath: "/mnt/data"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nfs
```

When I try to deploy the Replication Controller, the container is in the ContainerCreating status and I can see the following error in the journal of the minion

```
Feb 26 11:39:41 node-01 kubelet[1529]: Mounting arguments: 172.17.8.102:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/0e66affa-dc79-11e5-89b3-080027f84891/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs nfs []
Feb 26 11:39:41 node-01 kubelet[1529]: Output: mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
Feb 26 11:39:41 node-01 kubelet[1529]: E0226 11:39:41.908756    1529 kubelet.go:1383] Unable to mount volumes for pod "node-manager-eemi2_default": exit status 32; skipping pod
Feb 26 11:39:41 node-01 kubelet[1529]: E0226 11:39:41.923297    1529 pod_workers.go:112] Error syncing pod 0e66affa-dc79-11e5-89b3-080027f84891, skipping: exit status 32
Feb 26 11:39:51 node-01 kubelet[1529]: E0226 11:39:51.904931    1529 mount_linux.go:103] Mount failed: exit status 32
```

Used [2] Kubernetes-cluster-vagrant-cluster to setup my Kubernetes cluster.

my minion details:

```
core@node-01 ~ $ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=CoreOS
DISTRIB_RELEASE=969.0.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME="Coeur Rouge"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="CoreOS 969.0.0 (Coeur Rouge)"
```

[1] - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/nfs

[2] - https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem then realized that nfs-server.service status is disabled. After activating, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -2):

hence in order to resolve this nfs mount version issue by making the entry in /etc/nfsmount.conf in nfs server with Defaultvers=4 in the NFS server .The will resolved !!